# How can I reset the result set to its initial position (before first row) using mySQL's CPP driver?

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

The code to loop through a result set using the C++ driver for mysql is straightforward:

```
/* leaving out the code to create the connection and create the prepared statement... */

    sql::ResultSet *res;
    pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM foobar;");
    res = pstmt->executeQuery();
    
    while (res->next())
    {
        std::cout << res->getInt("id") << " " << res->getString("foo_bar_col") << std::endl;
    }
    
    // some smart way to reset the res object?
```

Throughout my application I would like to reuse this result set and loop through it again from the beginning to the end. I would therefore need to reset the result set to be positioned before its first row, just like it is when first retrieved. I could then simply do additional while loops on the same on the same object (`res`).

How do I do this? I could simply copy the object multiple times (once for each use), but there must be a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found this in the mysql c++ driver code https://github.com/anhstudios/mysql-connector-cpp/blob/master/cppconn/resultset.h

`res->beforeFirst();`

The documentation from Oracle seems not to be very good.